# How to open a new terminal window when using VIM

Tags: mac, terminal

does someone know how to open a new terminal window when opening a new text with VIM.

I would like to have an autarchic window which can be resized and closed while the other windows will stay as and where they are.

Regards

mmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [MacVIM](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) to handle this.  When you install MacVIM it should give you an option to install the command line shortcuts.

Then, in your Terminal, simply use `mvim` instead of `vi`:

```
mvim /path/to/your/file.txt
```

Or, if you are super lazy, add this to your `~/.profile`:

```
alias vi=mvim
```

This also allows you to associate text files with MacVIM in finder, so you always get the right application for your files, weather you open them in the GUI or not.

Comment: Bear in mind that this only opens a new macvim window **not** a new terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a little script like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript <<END
tell app "Terminal" to do script "vim"
END
```

Name this script v and make it executable :

```
chmod +x v
```

Then when you're in terminal, just execute the v script and it will open a new terminal window and run vim.

Alternatively, if you want to open a text file as part of this:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
on run argv
  tell app "Terminal" to do script "vim " & item 1 of argv
end run
```

Then just run v text.txt  and it will open a new terminal window, open vim, and open the text file called text.txt.   If text.txt doesn't exist, as usual, vim will create it in the buffer.

Comment: THX. At least it should open the text file i pointed at.

Comment: I updated my answer to allow you to open a text file pointed at the script with vim.